# Spring Security allowing the unauthorized requests

Tags: java, spring

I have created this system secured using the Spring Security. The problem is that all the configurations I have set up, are not being run and the requests are not being intercepted to be checked if they have a valid token or not. I am not using Spring Boot, however I have used some of the Spring libraries.

WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable()
                // dont authenticate this particular request
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/studentsystem2/login").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
                // store user's state.
                exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

JwtRequestFilter.java

```java
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;
        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }
        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = loginService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Basically, whenever I send a request to any endpoint , it will be executed perfectly well without checking if it has authorization or not. It needs to intercept the requests and allow only the ones that provide the right tokens.

Comment: It looks like `chain.doFilter(request, response)`,  which passes control onto the next filter in the chain, is always called at the end of `JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(...)` regardless whether the token is present and valid, or not. So, the processing of the request always carries instead of, say, returning `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: @gears so should I check that at first ?

Comment: This actually isn't a service that requires a valid Bearer token. So it is OK to always pass control onto the next filter in the chain - the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` - to try to authenticate the user by processing login form submission (/studentsystem2/login). I'd suggest looking into `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint` and what it does.

Comment: @gears thank you for your help. I appreciate that. All the best.

Comment: I think you have httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable(). For jwt based authentication you dont need to disable httpbasic security. hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

All the configurations are okay in the java class files. Although, for a non-Spring Boot application, you need to add the following configuration in the **web.xml** file of the application. That connects the stuff together.

```xml
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```